# Conditional check on click

Tags: jquery

I have an on click function that toggles a class.

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA classB");
    $(".secondary").toggleClass("classC classD");
));
```

I need to add a check which class is triggered and add an action based on it, something like.

```
if ( class == 'classA') {
  // do A
} else {
  // do B
}
```

Can it be done with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$(".main").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("classA classB");
  $(".secondary").toggleClass("classC classD");

  if ( $(this).hasClass('classA')) {
    // do A
  } else {
    // do B
  }
));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Couple minor tweaks:                                if ( $(this).hasClass('classA')) {